# Xamrin android app project not getting build

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am new at xamrin android app development. I have made basic menu drawer app in xamrin. But when I try to run this project it show following warning

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning     An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer. Please verify the Android SDK path and the  Java Development Kit path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu. Please see the logs for more details.          0
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   menu_drawer     1   Active

JDK path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21

And Android SDK Path
C:\Users\Suraj\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools > Option > Xamarin > Android. Are the Android SDK and JDK available?

- If yes, try updating your Android SDK and JDK.
- If no, download and install Android SDK and JDK to your computer.

Hope it could help.

Comment: Check if this link containing most common troubleshooting tips can help you: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/